# read POST data from within Oracle Apex application

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an webpage which posts some data and then redirects to a page within an oracle apex application. Is there a way to grab that posted data from within apex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no, APEX knows nothing about the session state persistence mechanism of other platforms.  However if the first web page saves the posted data to some agreed, accessible location (e.g. an Oracle table) then your APEX application can retrieve it.